# Does the place of GetMapping (Spring) matter when we want to return a template to client?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, backend

I was writing a Spring Boot application, and whenever the client requested to get "registration.html" template, the server should return it

I first put the GetMapping in my RegistrationController, and it worked, that is, when I access localhost:8080/registration, it does return me that page

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserRegistrationController(UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto() {
        return new UserRegistrationDto();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String registration() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) {
        userService.save(registrationDto);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

Then I decided to create a template controller, and put all GetMapping for templates there. But then when I try to access localhost:8080/registration again, it gives me an error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class TemplateController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration() {
        return "registration";
    }
}
```

So my question is, does it matter where I put the GetMapping? Or is there are some configurations I needed to fix, so the app knows where to find the GetMapping? But the thing is, the home() method in this TemplateController does return me /index successfully, so I thought it's not to do with this class

The summary of the log file is:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor
```

I think this line below might be the issue

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

My registration.html is as below, however the "user" object is only used for the POST request, not GET request for returning the page

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
<form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name"> Name </label>
        <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{name}"
               required autofocus="autofocus" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email"> Email </label>
        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{email}" required
            autofocus="autofocus" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password"> Password </label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password"
            th:field="*{password}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
        <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login
                            here</a></span>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Check the log file for more details about the 500 error

Comment: Are you using both controllers at the same time. Namely UserRegistrationController with /registration mapping and also the TemplateController with /registration mapping. You cannot assign a request mapping with the same mapping url to 2 different controller methods.

Comment: @Ahmet No I'm not using both. I'm only using one at a time, while the other is commented out.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @ElmarBrauch Would it be ok to paste the entire log to the question? I'll post the first line into the question for now: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'

Comment: Please put an empty User object into the model variable of your GetMapping.

Comment: @Ahmet Thank you! It now works! I'll post the solution now, could you pls explain why I should add the Model?

Comment: When returning to your GetMapping (ie. registration.html) your are expecting a User object because you are using thymeleaf form binding with th:object="${user}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Ahmet for the solution. The registration method under TemplateController is working now, and registration.html template is being returned, after I add a Model into the method. The complete code is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TemplateController {

    ...

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute(user);
        return "registration";
    }

    // below is the old version, which didn't work.
    // @GetMapping("/registration")
    // public String registration() {
        // return "registration";
    // }

    ...
}
```

And this method is only present in TemplateController class, not in UserRegistrationController class (if I put the method here, it has always been working, as described in the question)